# GitLab option not available in Jenkins Create a Pipeline in Blue Ocean screen

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, gitlab-api

I installed Jenkins GitLab plugin but GitLab connection not available in Jenkins Create a Pipeline in Blue Ocean screen .

[image]

Bitbucket link is available but GitLab is not available . Not sure why  ..

Comment: You don't need a special integration, select Git from the options and configure your GitLab repository. Here is a [GitLab Manual](https://gitlab.com/sela-labs/using-jenkins-blue-ocean) for doing so.